# Accessing Apollo Store like I used to go with Redux Store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, apollo, react-apollo

I'm following this tutorial for Apollo here: https://github.com/howtographql/react-apollo/blob/master/src/components/Header.js.

In the `Header.js` file they have:

`const userId = localStorage.getItem(GC_USER_ID)`

which seems to me a bit ugly: everytime `Header render()` is called you read from localStorage?

With `react-redux` I used to go with something like this:

```
render() {
  const { authentication } = this.props;
  ...
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  authentication: state.authentication
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logoutAction })(Navbar);
```

And also if I read from localStorage on every `render()` and let's say I wanna store in localStorage all my user's data (eg. `{username: "john", age: "15"}`) when I pass this `const` to one of my children components everytime it re-render because the `JSON.parse` makes it a new object! Everytime!

**How to have something like a Redux Store with Apollo?**

Answer (score 0):

Apollo's solution for managing state is through apollo-link-state.  Here is some [general info](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state.html) and the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/state.html).  After setting it up, you can then query state within a GraphQL query.

It has not reached 1.0 release yet, but it's usable and fairly easy to setup.  Their examples aren't great yet.  However, if you have some familiarity with GraphQL resolvers, it's fairly simple to setup.  I'm using it [here](https://github.com/colincmcc/Industry-Public-House/tree/GraphQL-%26-Redux/src/data) with success.